# XmlSerializer replaces non-ASCII characters with question mark '?'

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have an XML serializer that works great for ASCII but when non-ASCII characters are encountered they are replaced with a question mark '?'.  I believe I have it configured correctly for UTF8 and am unsure why it is doing this.

```
XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");

    settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.NewLineChars = "\n";
    settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None;
    settings.NewLineOnAttributes = false;
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(ms, settings))
    {
        xmls.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
    }

    string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());

    // remove the BOM character at the beginning which screws up decoding
    if (xml.Length > 0 && xml[0] != '<')
    {
        xml = xml.Substring(1, xml.Length - 1);
    }

    return xml;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the characters are actually question marks, and that the text editor you are using simply doesn't know how to represent non-ASCII characters (and is thus displaying a question mark)?

Comment: Yes indeed.  I have verified this.

Comment: @haxor I've just tested the above with "Jalapeño" - worked fine; your BOM-removal is a bit dodgy, though

Comment: Can it be due to OmitXmlDeclaration = true; that your viewer infers wrong encoding?

Comment: btw, `XmlTextWriter.Create` is actually `XmlWriter.Create`

Comment: Please show a concrete example (i.e. runnable) that demonstrates the problem you are seeing, i.e. with a sample DTO class and a sample non-ASCII string. I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi Marc, I found the issue elsewhere in my code.  Thank you so much for all of your help, I really appreciate it.  You were right, the issue was not with the serializer.

Comment: k; I do recommend tweaking how you get rid of the BOM though

Comment: Thanks Marc, I did per your recommendation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All looks fine here; tested with

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
...
string xml = Test(new Foo { Bar = "Jalapeño" });
```

output:

```
<Foo>
  <Bar>Jalapeño</Bar>
</Foo>
```

As a minor change, I removed the "remove the BOM character" code **completely**, and did that in the encoding explicitly:

```
settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
```

Additionally, if I include the xml declaration to check what encoding it thinks it is using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo>
  <Bar>Jalapeño</Bar>
</Foo>
```

So basically... cannot reproduce.